# How do I fix this localhost connection error with apache?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, localhost, httpd.conf

First of all, my apologies for the vague title. If anyone has any ideas for how I could have made the title more descriptive after reading the post I appreciate it! I'm pretty inexperienced with this whole thing so I appreciate any and all help.

I am trying to use PhpMyAdmin with Apache to connect to MySQL on macOS Big Sur 11.6.7. I successfully installed MySQL and MySQL Workbench to make sure that it was working. I ran into the problem that when I got to typing localhost in the browser, I got the message "It works!," but I couldn't, for the life of me, figure out how to get php code to run on the webpage, and instead it printed on the page. I tried a bunch of things, including uncommenting the line that allows Apache to use PHP, making sure DirectoryIndex included index.php, etc. Right now I'm receiving the following error when I try anything:

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using maverick-02.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

I've been getting this message everywhere and defining the ServerName variable in the httpd.conf file doesn't seem to change anything. Now when I refresh the localhost page, it says that it can't connect to the server "localhost". However, if I refresh again, it goes back to the "It Works" message. When I refresh again, it can't connect. Back and forth and back and forth. And my test.php file which was just printing out the code now cannot connect at all.

Does anyone have any ideas; is there anything else that I can add that would be helpful to better understand my problem?

Thank you all!

Edit: I forgot to mention a couple things about what I tried. I know that MacOS comes with Apache and PHP preinstalled, at least for now. I decided that I didn't know what was going on and so I decided to reinstall Apache with Brew. I don't know if that was a good idea or not because now I don't know what's going on, and the problems seemed to get worse after I tried that (i.e., the index.html file always displayed beforehand, in addition to the test.php code, both of which have been at least a little bit messed up). I'd also be willing to try deactivating Apache and starting totally anew, but I don't know if that makes sense.

Edit 2: I managed to get rid of the error message that I mentioned above. The problem, of course, was that I hadn't defined a global value for ServerName! I had done it in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf, but because I had mixed everything up by installing httpd on Brew, the httpd folder it recognized was in a different place, one that indeed did not have any globally defined ServerName variable. So I Brew uninstalled httpd, and the message went away, but nothing else happened. Still stuck on the exact same issues as before.

Comment: Is the file a .php? Your server name should be localhost.

Comment: The file I'm trying to load is a .php file. The server name is localhost as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Ok, I just found something really interesting. When I type in localhost:80 into my search bar I get the same oscillation between "It Works!" and not working, but it always works with localhost:8080. I'm going to keep playing around with this and report back.

Comment: I got the error message to go away, but not much else. I'm now using the default Apache build on MacOS.

Comment: We need a reproductible example. Look for http.conf http-vhost.conf, logs…

Comment: http.conf is a big file with lots in it. http-vhost.conf doesn't seem to exist. Where would it be? The error log is very sparse and doesn't return a whole lot. If it's okay to ask, what should I be looking for specifically that might indicate an error?

Comment: Ok, might have found something. On Chrome, localhost and localhost:80 never work, while localhost:8080 always does. I tried to uncomment the ```Listen 12.34.56.78:80``` line but nothing changed. I also changed the <IfDefine> statements right below that to both ```Listen 80```. Nothing changed. I ran ```sudo apachectl restart``` both times and so I think the changes should have saved. I don't know what else could be the problem?

Comment: Something more: when I ```sudo apachectl stop```, localhost:8080 still proudly proclaims that it is working. Very weird.

Comment: You have two apache versions then. Disable old one and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling any Apache2 instances should fix the problem. It is almost certain you have multiple instances on your OS, removing them all, and reinstalling should fix the issue.

Hopefully it helps!